# How can I use CASE to display special status cell if record exists in table 1 but not in table 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

Table1

| WIP1 | TimeStamp1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-04 |
| 2 | 2021-11-04 |
| 3 | 2021-11-04 |
| 4 | 2021-11-04 |

And table 2

| WIP2 | TIMESTAMP2 | Status2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-04 | RECEIVED |
| 2 | 2021-11-04 | PENDING |
| 4 | 2021-11-04 | RECEIVED |

I want to write a `SELECT` that display if the WIPS on table 1 already exists on table 2, if not, display a respective message (keeping the Table 2 message, i.e. pending or received and adding a message 'Not Received' if the WIP doesn't exist on Table 2), so, with the columns from my example:

| WIPR | TIMESTAMPR | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-04 | RECEIVED |
| 2 | 2021-11-04 | PENDING |
| 3 | 2021-11-04 | NOT RECEIVED |
| 4 | 2021-11-04 | RECEIVED |

Right now I've tried the following query:

```
select 
    t.WIP, t.TimeStamp, t.Operation 
from 
    Table1 w
join 
    Table2 t on t.WIP = w.WIP
union
select 
    w.WIP, w.DateaReleased, 'Not Received' operation 
from 
    Table1 w
left join 
    Table2 t on t.WIP = w.WIP
```

And it kind of works, but it duplicates the records:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `left join` and `case`, like below

```
select t1.wip1 as wipr, t2.TimeStamp2, 
       case when t2.wip2 is null then 'NOT RECEIVED' else t2.status2 end as status
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.wip1 = t2.wip2
```

Comment: Yup, this was it. I feel so dumb for using redundant code, thank you very much!

Comment: @MiguelV ur welcome,.

Comment: @MiguelV Be sure to ACCEPT the answer.

Comment: `coalesce(t2.status2, 'NOT RECEIVED')` will save you some typing.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to @Farshid Shekari 's answer.

You can also use `Coalesce`:

```
select t1.wip1 as wipr
      ,t1.TimeStamp1 as timestampr
      ,coalesce(t2.status2, 'not received')
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.wip1 = t2.wip2
```